# Repo not working in localhost using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I am new to this but I am trying to view a repository through localhost and I am receiving this php error in the mamp log:

```
PHP Warning:  require ..... failed to open stream: No such file or directory in  .......autoload_real.php on line 58
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 
....autoload_real.php on line 58
```

On Line 58 is the following:

```
function composerRequireec02cd7cea0c14cd8638fe929f5e7e81($file)
    {
        require $file;
    }
```

I think it might have something to do with the laravel version but i'm not sure. The other thing is that when I try to see errors in the laravel log there is no log in app/storage

Comment: try run in terminal "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: So what calls this rather wierdly names function `composerRequireec02cd7cea0c14cd8638fe929f5e7e81($file)` and what is the filename it is trying to `require`

Comment: @GeorginaPacey is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

First give the read permission to storage and bootstrap directory in your laravel project and then reload your laravel project in browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now after doing composer-dump autoload then a composer update, although I was looking for more of a global answer as to why this might be happening (i.e. outdated laravel version etc.). But thanks everyone!